# Which Third Party Tool(s) Installed?

Tags: managed-package, package, unmanaged-package

How can I identify which third party tools are currently integrated within my  instance?

Comment: Surely this question is resolved?

Answer (score 4):

[View Installed Package Details](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_package_detail.htm)

> To access the package detail page, from `Setup`, enter `Installed Packages` in the `Quick Find` box, select **`Installed Packages`**, and then click the name of the package that you want to view.

It's right under the **`Build`** section, not even nested.

[image: Setup Menu Screenshot]

Here's what the page looks like:

[image: Page Screenshot]

> #### Installed Packages
>
> [Help for this Page](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=distribution_managing_packages.htm&siteLang=en_US)
>
> On Force.com AppExchange you can browse, test drive, download, and install pre-built apps and components right into your salesforce.com environment. [Learn More about Installing Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=distribution_installing_packages.htm).
>
> Apps and components are installed in packages. Any custom apps, tabs, and custom objects are initially marked as "In Development" and are not deployed to your users. This allows you to test and customize before deploying. You can deploy the components individually using the other features in setup or as a group by clicking Deploy.
>
> Depending on the links next to an installed package, you can take different actions from this page.
>
> To remove a package, click **Uninstall**. To manage your package licenses, click **Manage Licenses**.

For each application, you can view:

- `Package Name`
- `Description` (not a column, it's listed under each package)
- `Publisher`
- `Version Number`
- `Namespace Prefix`
- `Install Date`
- `Limits` (checkbox if package consumes normal limits, see below for more detail)
- `Apps` (count)
- `Tabs` (count)
- `Objects` (count)

For the `Limits` checkbox, certified managed packages get their own set of limits for most per-transaction limits. See [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#certified_pkg_limits_section_title), specifically the **Per-Transaction Certified Managed Package Limits** section. The box is *unchecked* for such packages.

Comment: Maybe I understood this users question differently. Incase I want to find the versions of the integrations(Like SAP, SmartyStreets, etc) and not managed packages, how can I do it?Thanks